# Issue regarding JB System flow error in SalesCloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have an issue regarding JB System flow error in SalesCloud.
We are marketing cloud team and
as far as we know, this JB System flow error is occured when the journey builder activates which brings salesforce object into the entry source.

Our Salescloud team shared us this error message they are having during the interface process.

> CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can’t save this record because the
> JBSystem_Object_c_Process process failed. Give your Salesforce admin
> these details. Action name not found: null\n Error ID:
> 945074916-256432 (99337044)Action name not found: null\n Error ID:
> 945074916-256432 (99337044): []”

Could you share us the solution regarding the issue.

Comment: Open a support ticket, I don’t think anyone here will be able to help you..